# CoreImage CICrop returning 0x0 pixel image

Tags: ios, crop, cgimage, core-image

Apologies for so many questions today, Friday dead brain symptom setting in.

I have a CICrop filter:

```
[crop setValue:beginImage forKey:@"inputImage"];  //give the crop filter the beginImage
    [crop setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.0f Y:0.0f Z:_exportSize W:_exportSize] forKey:@"inputRectangle"];  //give the filter the size to crop to
    croppedImage = [crop valueForKey:@"outputImage"];  //set the output image, note it's still a CIImage at this point
```

Sadly, it's not working.  The image it crops ends up being 0x0 pixels.  A quick NSLog of _exportSize (which is a CGFloat) reveals it's 1024, but the log shows that the image post crop is 0x0.  I cannot work out why.

This code worked before.  The only difference being, I think, is that I used to crop UIImage no CIImages.  I'd rather not have to convert as I plan on doing other CoreImage stuff after the crop.

As I say, _exportSize is a CGFloat _exportSize; and logging it reveals it 1024.0000.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I gave up with Core Image for cropping and used this instead:

```
    -(UIImage *)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);

    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return cropped;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

`[crop setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.0f Y:0.0f Z:_exportSize.width W:_exportSize.height] forKey:@"inputRectangle"];`

instead of

`[crop setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.0f Y:0.0f Z:_exportSize W:_exportSize] forKey:@"inputRectangle"];`

help url http://gigliwood.com/weblog/Cocoa/Core_Image,_part_2.html

Z is supposed to be the width
W is supposed to be the height

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello.  _exportSize is a CGFloat, it doesn't have a width or height property.  But thanks for posting.  I can't figure out where the issue is.